# Trouble reading an Esri shape file using NetTopologySuite.IO.ShapeFile's CreateReader method

Tags: gis, shapefile, nettopologysuite

I have an Esri shape file with 10 polygons in it.

I need to read the shape file, correlated the polygons to their associated names (the .dbf table lists the Name of each polygon and its "key").

But... I can't seem to get the reader to return the polygons. Here's what I've got for code:

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

var shpPath = @".\Esri\RootNameOfShapeFile";
var geoFactory = GeometryFactory.Floating;
var reader = Shapefile.CreateDataReader(shpPath, geoFactory);

Console.WriteLine(reader.RecordCount); // outputs 10 which is correct
Console.WriteLine(reader.FieldCount); // outputs 6 which is correct
Console.WriteLine(reader.DbaseHeader.Fields[0].Name); // outputs "name" which is correct
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.Geometry.ToString()); // Nothing written. Reader.Read() always false
}

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

Halp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NetTopologySuite.IO.ShapeFile` is deprecated. You should use [`NetTopologySuite.IO.Esri`](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite.IO.Esri).